# Tracking data in Google polygon

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm creating a tracking application. All tracking data will be shown with in polygon drawn on map.

In my scenario a target may come into the defined area from out side or may go out of the defined of the area.Problem is how to define the start point when enters in area and end point when goes out of area. 
[image: In the below mentioned image when a target in only roaming with in area only].

Is there any method or hint so that I may create the start or stop point.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: Hi Joyson, i have attached an image to further clarify the scenario